# xCode 8 updates automatically NSManagedObject, is it?

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, xcode8

From xCode 8, xCode should update automatically NSManagedObjects after every DataModel modifies but I'm working on an old project which I've already update to Swift 3 but, every time I modify my DataModel, xCode doesn't update the corresponding ManagedObject.

Is it simply a "coming soon" feature or there something to check to enable this innovation?

Answer (score 0):

The [release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8_beta_2/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_8_beta_2.pdf) state that

> Automatic code generation is enabled and disabled on an entity by entity basis, and is enabled for all entities in new models using the Xcode 8 file format. This feature is available for any data model that has been upgraded to the Xcode 8 format.

You need to upgrade the model file to the new file format.

[image: Xcode 8.0 file format]

You may not be able to go back, so make sure your current version is committed to whatever VCS you use.